# Sending EditText.getText() to server. Works only on single words. How?

Tags: java, android, http, android-edittext

I have a pretty simple set up for a messaging application. I simply get the text from an EditText box and pass it as a parameter to a php page that adds it to my database. It works perfectly for one word entries. The moment I put in a space in the EditText box it doesn't work. I'm still fairly new at Android. I really do not understand how this could be happening. Does anyone know how this could happen?

Here is my onClick method:

```
    public void sendMessage(View v) {
Log.d("tag", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        username = prefs.getString("username", "null");



where = prefs.getString("chat", "null");
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptbox);

        function = new Functions();
        Editable messagetext;
messagetext = message.getText();


                response = function.sendMessage(username, where, messagetext.toString());
String theresponse = "";
theresponse = response;
                if (theresponse.compareTo("0") == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //message.setText(null);

                } else if (response.compareTo("9") == 0) {

                    // userent.setText("nine");

                }

    }
```

My function.sendMessage:

```
    public String sendMessage(String username, String where, String string){

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://abc.com/user_send.php?username="+username+"&where="+where+"&message="+string);

            HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
            post_request.setURI(website);


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);
            //executing actual request

                        //add your implementation here
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l+nl);

            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();


return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "ERROR";

        }

        }
```

How should I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode your message to make it "URL-safe." Spaces (and other special characters) cannot appear in URLs; this is why your browser will replace spaces with `%20` if you type them into the address bar. Try the following in function.sendMessage():

```
URI website = new URI("http://abc.com/user_send.php?username="+username+"&where="+where+"&message="+URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8"));
```

Notice the use of [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) at the end.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much sense. I can't believe I didn't think about that.

Comment: I'm getting a red line under URLEncode. "The method URLEncoder(String, String) is undefined for the type Functions"

Comment: Oh, whoops! I forgot to include the method. It should be `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")`. I'll update the Answer above too. Sorry about that!